# Print only the second array element

Tags: php, arrays

I have `$field_value` as an array, and I want to use the second array.

result `print_r( $field_value )`:

```
Array ( [0] => 5470 )
Array ( [0] => 5469 [1] => 5471 )
```

How to get only?

```
Array ( [0] => 5469 [1] => 5471 )
```

Comment: You do not have 2 arrays.  You have one array that keeps changing.  It looks like your `$field_value` exists inside a loop.  Can you show us the surrounding code?

Comment: As it seems like you don't show us your **full** and **real** code here and your code is in a loop, which means these are 2 different arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will grab the first value of every subarray in `$field_value` and put it in `$new` array which in result should contain what you need.

```
$new = array();
foreach($field_value as $k)
    $new[] = $k[0];
print_r($new);
```

Comment: Hi, the result of ($field_value[1]) is only 5471. I need the 5469 also.

Comment: Hi DeDee, Thank you for answering. Your answer solving my question which guide me to understand PHP:foreach. As Rocket Hazmat said, my array inside a loop. Now I'm able correct my code. Thank you.

Comment: @MonkimoE You're welcome, please allow me to refer you to the following article http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers